# How do I properly install and configure AMDGPU-PRO 17.10 driver?

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, amdgpu

I tried to install AMDGPU-PRO 17.10 driver step by step from official AMD site, but it wasn't successful.

When I fist tried to install it, after reboot I got "VGA: No video signal" from my monitor. I've loaded into recovery mode and checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and find, that driver require `/dev/dri/card0`, but there is no file or directory. I've uninstalled driver via recovery and successfully loaded into Ubuntu. But there is very interesting fact:

```
/dev/dri/card0 - exist
...Installing AMDGPU-PRO and rebooting...
/dev/dri/card0 - doesn't exist
...Uninstalling AMDGPU-PRO and rebooting...
/dev/dri/card0 - exist again
```

So, AMDGPU-PRO require `/dev/dri/card0`, but removes it after installing. How to deal with it and properly install driver?

Using Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS / 4.8.0-36-generic / AMD R9 380 videocard

`lspci | grep VGA` output:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga PRO [Radeon R9 285/380] (rev f1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found solution: just downgraded kernel from 4.8.0 to 4.4.10 and it works!

Answer (score 0):

you just have to blacklist the radeon  drivers in your /etc/default/grub such as this

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash blacklist=radeon"

then you can boot in ubuntu with your amdgpu-pro drivers on kernel 4.10.0+
it even work on ubuntu 17.04